# How to create a many to many relationship in SQLite DB

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, many-to-many, gtfs

Im trying to figure out how to create a many to many relationship between my train table, and station table. I know I need a intermediate table, which I created I feel like I'm going in a loop thinking about what to do. I'll have a link to the data that explains the relationships between my tables and my schema below. 
The only columns I'm looking at in this data are:

"GTFS_STOP_ID"(Id code for the Stop_Name), 
"Stop_Name"(Name of train station), and 
"Daytime Route"(which are the trains)

-One train can have many stations, and one station can also have many trains which is why in the "Daytime Routes" column you can see multiple trains. (For ex. N, W for the first row)

-How would I accurately depict relationships between these 3 columns in my csv, in my SQLITE database?

[Link to data(apologies for the csv in advance as it's the only thing I was able to find online](http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/subway/Stations.csv)

```
     cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS train""")
     cur.execute(
     """     CREATE TABLE train(
            pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            train_name VARCHAR
        );""")

    cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS station""")
    cur.execute(
    """     CREATE TABLE station(
            pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            stop_id VARCHAR,
            station_name VARCHAR

        );""")

    cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS train_station""")
    cur.execute(
    """     CREATE TABLE train_station(
            train_pk INTEGER,
            station_pk INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY (station_pk) REFERENCES station(pk)
            FOREIGN KEY (train_pk) REFERENCES train(pk)

        );"""
        )
```

Comment: The supplied schema looks like a good way to store the data for the relationships as described. What is the question?

Comment: So my question is, with my tables being as they are now would I be able to reference the same stop with multiple trains? 

i.e having the N, W trains reference the same stop_id R01 which will then give me the stop_name? Like how it is in the CSV file? My ideal goal is to create a 2 drop down menus. One with a list of all the trains, and when the user selects a train, the next drop down menu will return a filtered list of all the train stops for that train, once a user selects that stop, the next field will output the time it takes for that train to get to that station. Will this work?

Comment: It's all good until "_ the next field will output the time it takes for that train to get to that station._". Look at the data.  There is no time in the csv. How could the computer (or a human for that matter) know the _time_ between stops. Maybe `stop_times.txt' could help, I don't know.

Comment: Ohhh sorry I forgot to mention that part. Sooo what would happen next is once the user inputs the train and the station, there would be an api call that would look for when that train would arrive at that station, which would be the output. Since thats just an api call I assume it wouldn't be necessary to have a field to save that time since it's always updating real time as well.

Comment: Ah-ha. In that case, you're good to go. Happy coding!